# Extending DataGrid component, and adding buttons to it

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

I'd like to extend the standard DataGrid component in flex with mxml. But I want to add buttons to the bottom of the component. I've tried attempting the following but its not working...

Am I adding the Button to the wrong element?

```
<mx:DataGrid xmlns:fx = "http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
             xmlns:mx = "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
             xmlns:s = "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            override protected function createChildren():void
            {
                super.createChildren();

                listContent.addChild(button);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Button id="button" label = "asdasdas"/>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Got it. All I needed to do was replace listContent.addChild(button); with...

parent.addChild(button);

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand how this answers your question.  That won't actually add the button to as a child to the DataGrid; and in the original code to your question you weren't adding the child in ActionScript at all.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define "Not working"!  Are you getting compiler errors?  Or runtime errors?  Or is the button just not showing up?  I'll assume the latter.

The DataGrid does not have any mechanism for positioning or laying out it's children.  Your button most likely has a height and width of zero and resides at position 0,0; making it effectively invisible.  Many Flex container classes have the ability to size and position their children; but the DataGrid is not a container and does not provide built in functionality for that.  It focuses, primarily, on working with the columns array.

You will need to override the updateDisplayList() to position the function.  Quite possibly you will need to make changes to commitProperties() and measure() along the way.  You may also need to re-work how the columns are positioned and sized  as to not interfere with your new button.  If stuff is locked away in private methods (which is probable) then you're in a for a not-so-fun-time.

Read up on the [Flex Component LifeCycle methods](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/ascomponents_advanced_2.html) for more information and also review the DataGrid code to figure out what it does.

You may have an easier time just putting the button and DataGrid in a container, and treating that container as a single entity instead of trying to get a Button renderered inside of the DataGrid.

Comment: I agree with the last point. If you need a component with a button and a datagrid to use around your application, wrap them both into custom component instead of messing with DataGrid